# Resize LVM on KVM CentOS 6 VM

Tags: linux, partitioning, virtual-machine, centos

I've got a base image that I'm booting my VM's from. The base image is only 1.5GB. Different VM's will have different requirements for disk space. I've setup the VM with the default setting:

```
VolGroup
  -lv_root
  -lv_swap

/dev/vda 1.5GB
  -/dev/vda1 /boot 500MB
  -/dev/vda2 LVM2  1GB
```

So /dev/vda2 is where VolGroup resides. Let's say I need a new VM that needs to be 100GB. I use LVM at the host level so I can resize the VM's disk at will, but this isn't reflected until the partition table is altered on the guest VM.

**EDIT**: I've tried adding another partition but that causes the system to not be bootable because LVM is looking in the new partition for LVM data. So the new partition table would look like this:

```
/dev/vda 100GB
  -/dev/vda1 /boot 500MB
  -/dev/vda2 LVM2  1GB
  -/dev/vda3       98.5GB
```

**What's the quickest or easiest way for me to get from the current 1GB LVM to a 100GB LVM?**

Comment: Are you sure the *LVM is looking in the new partition for LVM data* is correct? As it should not. It will try to read the header to see if it is Physical Volume, but nothing more that that. What's the output? Following should work: `vgextend VolGroup /dev/vda3 && lvextend -r -L+10G VolGroup/lv_root`. Do you really want all space in the /? Depends on the use but having separate /home is usually a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up re-creating the partition behind the LVM using fdisk. Here's my awesome script that works on CentOS 6/7 servers:

```
ssh root@vmip "fdisk /dev/vda << EEOF
                d
                2
                n
                p
                2
                $firstpartborder

                t
                2
                8e
                w
                EEOF" >> /dev/null 2>&1

echo
echo "-------- Rebooting VM to Sync Disks ----------"
ssh root@$vmip "reboot"
echo "------ Waiting for the VM to come back up ----"
sleep 20
echo "--------Extending LVM to fill disk -----------"
ssh root@$vmip "pvresize /dev/vda2; lvextend -r -l +100%FREE $lvmname; " > /dev/null 2>%1
```

firstpartborder is the first sector of the original partition. This is very important as this was breaking my initial efforts.

I hope this helps anybody with similar issues.